# Save the output of darkice or icecast2 stream to file (mp3)?

Tags: sound, mp3, icecast

I successfully set up a icecast2 server with darkice (ubuntu server 20.04.1 LTS (focal)) on a raspberrypi) to stream audio inside of my network. I now would like to be able to go back and listen to recordings of everything that happens on the stream by having mp3 files of the source.

I am not really sure where to start with this I do not have much in depth experience working with linux. I did some searching before this and found a script (I think) [on this site](https://groups.drupal.org/node/8475) but got errors when I tried to run it. I’m assuming it may either be for a different flavor of linux or things have changed in the 10 years since it was released.

If anyone could help me with this or at least point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I was mistaken about thge version it is actually Ubuntu server 20.01.1 LTS. Codename focal. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I found to be easy enough to implement was to just curl the icecast2 stream itsself. The solution below is what i use with a cron job which runs every 30 mins, it records for 31 mins giving me 1 min of overlap between recordings and sets the file name to the time of start of recording.

```
sudo curl --output /media/usb/"$(TZ=America/New_York date +'%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p').mp3" http://(icecast2 mount point) --max-time 1860
```